# Efficiently find set differences and generate random sample

Tags: r, set, sample, set-difference

I have a very large data set with categorical labels `a` and a vector `b` that contains all possible labels in the data set:

```
a <- c(1,1,3,2)   # artificial data
b <- c(1,2,3,4)   # fixed categories
```

Now I want to find for each observation in `a` the set of all remaining categories (that is, the elements of `b` excluding the given observation in `a`). From these remaining categories, I want to sample one at random.

My approach using a loop is

```
goal <- numeric() # container for results

for(i in 1:4){

d       <- setdiff(b, a[i]) # find the categories except the one observed in the data
goal[i] <- sample(d,1)      # sample one of the remaining categories randomly

}

goal
[1] 4 4 1 1
```

However, this has to be done a large number of times and applied to very large data sets. Does anyone have a more efficient version that leads to the desired result?

EDIT:

The function by akrun is unfortunately slower than the original loop. If anyone has a creative idea with a competitive result, I'm happy to hear it!

Comment: Done, thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that resampling the labels that are equal to the labels in the data is an even faster approach, using

```
 test = sample(b, length(a), replace=T)
  resample = (a == test)

  while(sum(resample>0)){

  test[resample] = sample(b, sum(resample), replace=T)
  resample = (a == test)
  }
```

Updated Benchmarks for N=10,000:

```
Unit: microseconds
                               expr       min        lq       mean    median         uq       max neval
                               loop 14337.492 14954.595 16172.2165 15227.010 15585.5960 24071.727   100
                              akrun 14899.000 15507.978 16271.2095 15736.985 16050.6690 24085.839   100
                           resample    87.242   102.423   113.4057   112.473   122.0955   174.056   100
        shree(data = a, labels = b)  5195.128  5369.610  5472.4480  5454.499  5574.0285  5796.836   100
 shree_mapply(data = a, labels = b)  1500.207  1622.516  1913.1614  1682.814  1754.0190 10449.271   100
```

Comment: This is great!. *"Almost"* vectorized so gonna be hard to beat. The only room for improvement seems to be that this could potentially require multiple `while` iterations to re-sample  any value. I tried some ideas to overcome that but didn't work out in terms of performance. Anyways, nice out-of-box thinking. +1

Answer (score 3):

We can use `vapply`

```
vapply(a,  function(x) sample(setdiff(b, x), 1), numeric(1))
```

---

```
set.seed(24)
a <- sample(c(1:4), 10000, replace=TRUE)
b <- 1:4
system.time(vapply(a,  function(x) sample(setdiff(b, x), 1), numeric(1)))
#   user  system elapsed 
#  0.208   0.007   0.215
```

Comment: I was just trying to compare scalability. Interestingly, the following code results in an error (original example runs fine!). Do you have an idea why?

`a <- sample(c(1:4), 10000, replace=T)`
`b <- c(1,2,3,4)`
`vapply(a,  function(x) sample(setdiff(b, a), 1), numeric(1))`
`Error in sample.int(length(x), size, replace, prob) : invalid first argument`

Comment: @Mr.Zen. in the `setdiff`, I had a typo, sorry, it is `x`

Comment: Thanks for the correction! Unfortunately, the proposed approach is even slower than the original loop (see top post edit).

Comment: @Mr.Zen. I thought you want to specifically use the `setdiff` function.

Comment: Sorry for being unclear! Using `setdiff` was just my first intuition, it's not necessary at all.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** Here's a fast version with `mapply`. This method avoids calling `sample()` for every iteration so is a bit faster. -

```
mapply(function(x, y) b[!b == x][y], a, sample(length(b) - 1, length(a), replace = T))
```

---

Here's a version without `setdiff` (`setdiff` can be a bit slow) although I think even more optimization is possible. -

```
vapply(a, function(x) sample(b[!b == x], 1), numeric(1))
```

---

**Benchmarks -**

```
set.seed(24)
a <- sample(c(1:4), 1000, replace=TRUE)
b <- 1:4

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  akrun = vapply(a,  function(x) sample(setdiff(b, x), 1), numeric(1)),
  shree = vapply(a, function(x) sample(b[!b == x], 1), numeric(1)),
  shree_mapply = mapply(function(x, y) b[!b == x][y], a, sample(length(b) - 1, length(a), replace = T))
)


Unit: milliseconds
         expr     min       lq      mean   median       uq      max neval
        akrun 28.7347 30.66955 38.319655 32.57875 37.45455 237.1690   100
        shree  5.6271  6.05740  7.531964  6.47270  6.87375  45.9081   100
 shree_mapply  1.8286  2.01215  2.628989  2.14900  2.54525   7.7700   100
```

Comment: I tried `sample(b[-x], 1)` but it only seems to be about 10% faster

Comment: @BenBolker, Sorry, I might be missing something, but doesn't `b[-x]` remove the `x`-th value and not value `x`?